# Can't run Rails app after "deploying" hidden file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, credentials

I was trying to hide my credentials before pushing the repository publicly, as I should.
For that, I've used [this](https://medium.com/swlh/an-easy-way-to-manually-hide-an-api-key-in-a-simple-rails-app-317ca1f823a8) resource, which worked perfectly on development mode.
For short, I've assigned global variables inside a ".api_keys.rb" file, called them on the appropriate file (devise.rb on this case) and added it to .gitignore.
Then I pushed it to GitHub. Later on, I needed to clone this one last commit. But then when I try running it, it responds with "cannot load such file -- /path/.api_keys.rb".

What am I missing? I can provide any more details if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a file to `.gitignore` means that the file is removed from the repository and only exists locally because the file is *ignored by git* completely.

Because it is not stored in your git repository anymore it is not available to remote servers or other developers when pulling the repository from GitHub.

To fix this your need to remove the file from `.gitignore` and push it again when it still exists on your machine or you need to recreate it.

Btw the way to store, for example, API keys securely in Rails is to use encrypted files. I suggested reading in the [Rails Guides about Environmental Security and Custom Credentials].(https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security)

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying and suggestions. I'll try them out as soon as possible and get back at you.

Comment: @JakeD.: Strictly speaking, just listing a file in `.gitignore` *doesn't* cause it to stop being committed. What it does is stop it from being auto-added to Git's index *if* it's *currently untracked*, and also stop `git status` from complaining about it. So it's kind of complicated. But in Git, every commit is a *full snapshot of all the files Git knows about*, and old snapshots cannot be changed, so if there's an old committed copy, it's still there in the repo.

Comment: That said, do use encrypted files, don't ever store keys as cleartext if you can avoid it.

Comment: That is right. A file will be still in the history when a file was once committed to a repository but later removed. That means if you had something committed to the history and then move it into a encrypted file then you need to change and rotate those keys because otherwise attackers could just read the keys from the file in the history.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks, that was helpful about .gitignore. But the app is still not running after I clone it. It still returns "cannot load such file -- /path/.api_keys.rb". I've already deleted this file from gitignore and I can't find the "api_keys.rb" file anywhere to delete it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @JakeD. I am not sure about the current status: Do you still want to use the `/path/.api_keys.rb? Then you need to make sure that it exists in your local branch and that you commit and push it. If you do not want to use it anymore, then you can delete it and you must certainly remove references to that file from your code base.

Comment: @spickermann Ok, I finally found there the ".api_keys.rb" was being required on my local repo. For some reason, it was not being detected before. Again, appreciate the help!